How to Change Bullet Shapes Based on Frame Attributes (e.g., frametitle) in Beamer
I would like to change the bullet shapes based on certain attributes of each frame. For example, I want to use different bullet shapes depending on the frametitle of each frame.

Use a circle bullet when the frametitle is "circle".
Use a rectangle bullet when the frametitle is "rectangle".

Here’s a minimal example of what I have:
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169,compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{circle} Sample text \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{rectangle} Sample text \end{frame}
\end{document}

My expected result:



Please help me with tags. I am not sure if they are correct. Thanks

As a proof of concept, you could change the miniframe symbol based on e.g. the section/slide number. The code below will change the symbol for the second slide in the first section. Look for <= change number of exception here in the code to see where you can change the number and icon.
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169,compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\makeatletter
\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#1>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
      \ifnum#2=0%
        \beamer@ypos@offset=1\relax%
      \fi
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
      \advance\beamer@ypos by \beamer@ypos@offset\relax
    \fi%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
          \ifnum#1=1%
          \ifnum#3=2% <= change number of exception here
            \setbeamertemplate{mini frame}{\textbf{x}}%
            \setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{x}%
            \setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}{x}%
          \fi\fi
          \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
          \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
              \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
              \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%\beamer@minislidehilight%
              \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%\beamer@minisliderowhilight%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              %\color{fg!50!bg}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
            \fi%
          \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            %\color{fg!50!bg}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
          \fi%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{circle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{rectangle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{circle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}

\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{circle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{rectangle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{circle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}

\end{document}


With beamer v3.72 or newer, you will be able to use the same approach to access beamer's pre-defined mini frame templates like box or tick:
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169,compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\makeatletter
\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#1>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
      \ifnum#2=0%
        \beamer@ypos@offset=1\relax%
      \fi
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
      \advance\beamer@ypos by \beamer@ypos@offset\relax
    \fi%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
          \ifnum#1=1%
          \ifnum#3=2% <= change number of exception here
            \setbeamertemplate{mini frames}[box]%
          \fi\fi
          \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
          \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
              \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
              \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%\beamer@minislidehilight%
              \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%\beamer@minisliderowhilight%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              %\color{fg!50!bg}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
            \fi%
          \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            %\color{fg!50!bg}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
          \fi%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{circle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{rectangle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{circle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}

\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{circle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{rectangle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{circle} 
Sample text 
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Maybe this is already sufficient for the OP, but the question was about matching the text of the frametitle, not the slide number.

@Marijn Have fun implementing a solution based on the frametitle :)

Thanks samcarter, you are amazing!

@Sadegh You're welcome!

This is not 100% what I wanted but surely it is good enough :-)

@Sadegh That's what is possible without writing your own navigation bar

Apart form pagenumber, what are other elements that can be used in this solution?

maybe section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number ?

@Sadegh most of them

Perfect <3 <3 <3

How can I adopt the code to work with many pages? lets say I want pages 2,3,5,6 to have different bullet shape

I found this soltuion but hope there is a simpler way:
\ifnum#3=2 \else \ifnum#3=3 \else \ifnum#3=5 \else \ifnum#3=6
....
\fi \fi \fi \fi

@Sadegh Either copy the \ifnum#3=2 \fi block as often as necessary of find another criterium which matches all the slides.

There is a problem: this code (the first one) applies the change on every 2nd page of each section. But I want it to apply the changes on overall page

@Sadegh See my updated answer

Excelent answer! thanks

There is still one issue: when selecting the sections without "x" , the "x" in the other section has the wrong color.

https://i.postimg.cc/PqZdCqyy/image.png

@Sadegh It is up to you to define the symbol in whichever colour you want in \setbeamertemplate{mini frame}{\textbf{x}}%             \setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{x}%             \setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}{x}%

(if you use the second solution with the beamer dev version from github, the colour will change automatically https://i.sstatic.net/JpbnfzK2.png )

the second solution dost work for me in local. I also tried it in overleaf and teh result is the same:
https://postimg.cc/CnT5bRQf

@Sadegh The second solution needs the beamer dev version
